# Are spherical harmonics a basis for $H^1$?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, spherical-harmonics

We know that spherical harmonics are a complete orthonormal system for $L^2(\mathbb{S}^2)$. Is it true that they are also a complete orthonormal system for $H^1(\mathbb{S}^2)$?

Furthermore, is it true that the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian on a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ are a complete orthonormal system?

I expect the answer to be no, I did some research on the internet and could find no answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $H^1 \subset L^2$ so if the spherical harmonics $\in H^1$... and the eigenfunctions of a linear operator are orthonormal [if the operator is normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_operator), is the Laplacian always normal whatever the shape of $\Omega$ ?

Comment: Maybe I can rephrase the question: can be any $H^1$ function on the sphere be approximated _in the $H^1$ norm_ by finite linear combinations of spherical harmonics?

Comment: no Ok, write $ u =\sum a_n \Psi_n$ with $\Psi$ the spherical harmonics and the series converges in $L^2$. does it still converge in $H^1$ ? does it imply $u \not \in H^1$ ? and did you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Differentiability_properties ?

Comment: @user1952009 A quick look at the wiki page reveals: $\sum a_{ml} \Psi_{ml}$ will be in $H^1$ if $\sum_l (l^2+1)\frac 1 {2l +1} \sum_{m= -l}^l a_{ml}^2 < \infty$. Then I guess one can define $H^1(\mathbb{S}^2)$ both by decomposition with spherical harmonics and by the usual definition with existence of weak derivative and boundedness in $L^2$ of it. How do we prove that these two are equivalent?